# Managing timed events that should not clash

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and i have been studying and playing around with event timing and the setInterval and setTimeout functions. i have a simple code below that displays a greeting "Good Morning" after an interval of 5 seconds and "How are you doing today?" after an interval 10 seconds.

```
script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function () {document.write("Good Morning")}, 5000); 

    setInterval( function () {document.write("How are you doing today?")}, 10000);


    </script>
```

The problem is after every 10 seconds, both will obviously appear at the same time and that's not the ideal situation. How would i rectify this without changing the times in the code above? Some sort of way to ensure the greeting "Good Morning" gets the first priority.

Comment: so each 10 seconds you want a delay between "Good Morning" and "How are you doing today?" ? What delay?

Comment: Use an interval of 10 seconds for both – by delay _starting_ one of the intervals by a timeout of 5 secs …?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit At 10 seconds, both "Good Morning" and "How are you doing today?" will appear at the same time right? so the delay am talking about is like forcing a priority on the "Good Morning" so that   "How are you doing today?" appears after  the greeting  "Good Morning" has ended. I hope i am making sense

Comment: @CBroe like a combination of the setInterval and setTimeout functions right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use an interval of 10 seconds for both, and *delay* starting one of the intervals by a timeout of 5 seconds.

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log("Good Morning", new Date)
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log("How are you doing today?", new Date)
    }, 10000);
}, 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roz5z31w/

(Note that I replaced `document.write` by `console.log`, so you have to check your browser’s JS console to see the result. As to why you should not use `document.write` any more today, please do some research.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "Good Morning" and "How are you doing today?" messages one by one in every 5 seconds use:

```
!function greet(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        log('Good Morning');
         setTimeout(function(){
            log('How are you doing today?');
            greet();
        }, 5000); 
    }, 5000);   
}();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/494m3sec/2/)

[advanced version](http://jsfiddle.net/494m3sec/3/)

[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/494m3sec/5/)

If you want another behavior please clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually wanted to get the solution to that problem above and see if i can apply the logic to provide a solution to another problem whereby i have 2 array queues A and B with 5 items each. Items in queue A have to be dequeued after every 30 seconds and the items in queue B after every 60 seconds. However the dequeueing should take priority in A since after 60 seconds both queues will be dequeued at the same time. i want want to enable some sort of delay when the dequeueing times clash

Comment: @Gilbert check updated link. 1000 delay is only for debug, for your logic change both to 30000

Comment: I have done that but still both queues seem to get dequeued at the same time when both their times clash. is there a way of comparing the times of dequeue and if they happen at the same time i can enable the non-prioritized queue to delay for a few seconds while the prioritized one completes dequeueing?

Comment: @Gilbert If dequeuing is not async operation, the second (non-prioritized) queue cannot begin dequeuing before first.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. guess i need to do more research there.  If i may ask do you know of another way or algorithm to use instead of the setInterval and the setTimeout functions?

Comment: @Gilbert algorithm of what? In js there are only 2 functions for async functions execution after delay: setTimeout and setInterval.

Comment: I asked since i will be animating a little bit. i found the solution here though http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/alternative-to-setinterval-and-settimeout

Comment: @Gilbert If [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame) doesn't confuse you, `requestAnimationFrame` is a better solution